# Splitting the range of an axis, to reduce white space

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to remove specific xtic values (hours axis) in my graph that are not being used with other data. To be precise, I want to keep the following Xranges [0:5, 12:14], but not the xrange [6:11]. This is to help space out my data, since the unused space is currently smashing them together. I will attach a picture to visualize. Thank you for any help[image: graph example]

I tried 'set xrange [0:5, 12:14]' but it did not work.

Comment: How is your data organized? 1 file with x,y,z in 7 blocks or 7 files? Please give a data example or describe the data structure and show minimal code.

Comment: Is your problem solved / question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know the exact structure of the data because the plotting code needs to adapt to it.
For the following example the data structure is as follows:

- 7 blocks separated by double blank lines with `x y z` data.
- Each block has a constant x value (from the values `0 1 2 3 5 12 14`) whereas y and z vary.
- If you have double blank lines you can address the blocks via `index` (check `help index`).
- The x values are not equidistant, but you basically want to make them appear equidistant.
  For this, you can use the pseudocolumn -2 (check `help pseudocolumns`) which contains the block number starting from 0.
- The xtic label is used from column 1 (check `help xticlabels`).

**Code:**

```
### plot "non-equidistant" data equidistant
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
    do for [x in "0 1 2 3 5 12 14"] {
        do for [y=-40:40] {
            print sprintf("%s %g %g", x, y, (16-x)*cos(0.05*y)**2)
        }
        print "\n\n"
    }
set print

set xyplane at 0
set grid x,y
set view 60,140
set key at screen 0.3, screen 0.95 noautotitle
set xrange [-0.5:6.5]

splot for [i=0:6] $Data u -2:2:3:xtic(1) index i w l lc i
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]